# Android Exception when starting activity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android

I'm having this exception when my android application in starting:

```
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{es.landesoft/es.landesoft.LandeSoftActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-14 16:40:41.725: E/AndroidRuntime(11341):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
```

This is the beginning of the Class and the Oncreate Method. I know you can not use
System Services before onCreate() and I think I am not doing it because I only fire
the code with the layout buttons.

```
public class LandeSoftActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView lblEnvio;
    EditText txtDestinatarios;
    EditText txtAsunto;
    EditText txtMensaje;
    private String ResStr;
    private String ResEnvio;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button botonEnviar = (Button) findViewById(es.landesoft.R.id.btnSend);

        botonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Thread Hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        ResEnvio= EnviarEMailWS();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                });
                Hilo.start();
                lblEnvio.setText(ResEnvio);

            }
        });

        Button BtnSysInfo = (Button) findViewById(es.landesoft.R.id.btnSysInfo);
        BtnSysInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Thread Hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                    ResStr =RequestWSInfo();
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);                        
                    }
                });

                Hilo.start();
                ShowToastMsg(ResStr, 12000);

            }
        });

        lblEnvio = (TextView) findViewById(es.landesoft.R.id.textView1);
        txtDestinatarios = (EditText) findViewById(es.landesoft.R.id.editText1);
        txtAsunto= (EditText) findViewById(es.landesoft.R.id.txtAsunto);
        txtMensaje= (EditText) findViewById(es.landesoft.R.id.txtMensaje);
```

I hope you can help me. I guess the problem is the ProgressDialog but I am not launching the window.

Thanks in advance!.
    }

Comment: Is this all the code in your Activity? If not, post the rest please.

Comment: Ok I Found the problem, sorry. I copy and pasted some code and didn't realize it was declaring ProgressDialog dialog using ProgressDialog.Show() method that is not allowed as a global var because it use System Services. Thanks Jan-Henk for your interest.

Comment: Be sure to post your comment as an answer and mark it as correct to help others!

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I'm still learning how StackOverflow works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I Found the problem, sorry. I copy and pasted some code and didn't realize it was declaring ProgressDialog dialog using ProgressDialog.Show() method that is not allowed as a global var because it use System Services. Thanks Jan-Henk for your interest.